# module as no attribute - self.variable.function(self)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pyqt5

I have a module call pcb_files.py that only have some imports like this -> import read

Then I have another module call Easy.py, that have a class (Mainwindow) and a method/funtion (function_pcb1)

```
Class MainWindow(xxx,xxx)
    .....
    .....
    def func_pcb1(self):
        pcb_files.read.main(self)
```

Right now everytime I press a pushbutton in my app I run the funtion "main" that is inside "read". So far so good

What I want:

```
def func_pcb1(self):
    script=self.nome_do_script
    pcb_files.script.main(self)
```

Like you see in, now I have this : `script=self.nome_do_script` where "script" is a string type.

And now I just want to change one thing, in the place of "read" I want to put the "script" like i do in the image but it gives me an error -> AttributeError: module 'pcb_files' has no attribute 'script'

Resuming, instead of call whats inside "script" variable, it's calling the name script itself.

Now you're asking why do you want that ? -> Answer: I want to call, and show to the user, in my app different files that will do different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`something.other` is what Python calls attribute access, where `"other"` is the attribute name. If you want to access an attribute with a dynamic name, you can use `getattr`.

```
def func_pcb1(self):
    script = self.nome_do_script
    getattr(pcb_files, script).main(self)
```

In the long term, you'll want to learn how to use dictionaries for these kinds of things.